# Cyclic subgroups and greatest common divisor

Tags: group-theory, gcd-and-lcm, cyclic-groups

Let be $G=\langle x\rangle$ a cyclic group and $H$ the subgroup of $G$ that contains $x^m$ and $x^n$. I have to prove that $H=\langle x^{(n,m)}\rangle$; where $(n,m)$ denotes the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$.

I know that there exist $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$\alpha n + \beta m = (n,m);$$
which implies, since $H\leq G$ and $x^m,x^n\in H$, that
$$x^{(n,m)} = x^{\alpha n + \beta m} = x^{\alpha n}x^{\beta m}\in H.$$
This proves that $\langle x^{(n,m)}\rangle\subseteq H$.

I'm having a hard time trying to prove that $H\subseteq \langle x^{(m,n)}\rangle$. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What does an arbitrary element of $H$ look like? Now use the definition of gcd.

Comment: I don't think the other inclusion is true since in $\mathbb{Z}$, $6, 12 \in \langle 2 \rangle$, but $\gcd(6,12) = 6$.